# Reattaching self to screen - Linux/Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, ssh, gnu-screen

I occasionally use **screen** within linux.

Every now and then my connection plays up and I lose access to the ssh shell, when I try to reattach myself to the screen instance this is what I get:

```
There is a screen on:
     2690.pts-0.localhost    (09/03/10 12:56:08)     (Attached)
There is no screen to be resumed.
```

---

**Any idea what I could do in this case?** I guess screen believes I'm still attached, while I'm not.

:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case try:

```
% screen -x 2690.pts-0.localhost
```

Answer (score 2):

Simpler would be

```
screen -d -r
```